# invalid from flag value spe: pull access denied for spe, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, powershell, sitecore

I am trying to intsall powershall in sitecore using docker but I am not unable to build

I am getting the below error:
[image]

Here is the mssql-int file. Here I added the spe line:
[image]

and this is `docker-compose-override.yml` file code. I have already set the variable in env file:
[image]

I have update all the docker files and after that I am doing the build command but I am getting the error.

Comment: Where do you set the variables that you're using in the docker-compose-override.yml ?